# A question about absolutely continuous measure

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Let $\nu$ be a finite measure such that $\nu << \mu$.

My question is that, do we always have a constant $C>0$ such that $\nu(A)\leq C\mu(A)$ for all measurable $A$? If not, can you give me a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: $\mu=$ Lebesgue measure on $(0,1), \nu (E)=\int_E x^{-1/2} d\mu (x)$

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks.